APK not creating using eas
Getting this error on running this command: eas build -p android
    ✖ Compressing project files
    Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build
    Reason: Cannot copy 'C:\Users\adeel' to a subdirectory of itself, 'C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\759b29c7-95c2-46d3-a95e-a3da46ae90bc-shallow-clone'.
 Error: build command failed.

I just wanna create a simple APK for android app using react native.
I tried this many times.

it started working when I shift my project to another drive
apk is building now
Thanks
